# kafka + how to delete consumer group

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, producer-consumer

in our kafka cluster ( based on HDP version - 2.6.5 , and kafka version is 1.0 ) , and we want to delete the following consumer group

```
/usr/hdp/2.6.5.0-292/kafka/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh  --list --bootstrap-server kafka01:6667| grep -i test
Note: This will not show information about old Zookeeper-based consumers.

test_group_0e1e37b0-603e-4ffd-9b21-90a3adf597ca
```

but when we try to delete it we get:

```
/usr/hdp/2.6.5.0-292/kafka/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --zookeeper zookeeper01:2181 --delete --group test_group_0e1e37b0-603e-4ffd-9b21-90a3adf597ca
To enable GC log rotation, use -Xloggc:<filename> -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=<num_of_files>
where num_of_file > 0
GC log rotation is turned off
Note: This will only show information about consumers that use ZooKeeper (not those using the Java consumer API).

Error: Delete for group 'test_group_0e1e37b0-603e-4ffd-9b21-90a3adf597ca' failed because group does not exist.
```

what is wrong with above command ?

[image]

more details from Kafka Ambari config:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the output says, group doesn't exist with `--zookeeper`

You need to keep your arguments consistent; use `--bootstrap-server` to list, delete, and describe, assuming your cluster supports this

However, groups delete themselves with no active consumers, so you shouldn't need to run this

Comment: but if I use with bootstarp-server I get:

Comment: option '[delete]' is only valid with '[zookeeper]'. Note that there's no need to delete group metadata for the new consumer as the group is deleted when the last committed offset for that group expires.

Comment: example: I use /usr/hdp/2.6.5.0-292/kafka/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server kafka01:6667,kafka02:6667:kafka03:6667 --delete --group ...

Comment: or /usr/hdp/2.6.5.0-292/kafka/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server kafka01:6667 --delete --group

Comment: so both option without success

Comment: Basically, your consumers aren't committing offsets to Zookeeper. Therefore you cannot delete the group. As it says, they're automatically deleted. The number of bootstrap servers you give doesn't matter

Comment: but after few days we have still this this consumer group , so what you means if they will automatically deleted , when? and how to force this deletion?

Comment: Look at the `offsets.retention.minutes` value in the broker configs

Comment: from ambari kafka the value is 86400000

Comment: Convert that from minutes

Comment: yes I mean what U say its 60K days

Comment: Note that the default is 7 days. I'm not sure why someone would make that be over a decade

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242269/discussion-between-jessica-and-onecricketeer).

Comment: I see offsets.retention.minutes

After a consumer group loses all its consumers (i.e. becomes empty) its offsets will be kept for this retention period before getting discarded. For standalone consumers (using manual assignment), offsets will be expired after the time of last commit plus this retention period.